# Making a batch file to hide the local disk drive

Tags: batch-file

I have made batch file that can run diskpart but I want  to do the following commands:

```
diskpart> list volume
diskpart> select volume 2
diskpart> remove letter d
```

Comment: Drum Role - The question is?

Answer (score 1):

Put your three commands in a text file:

```
list volume
select volume 2
remove letter d
```

Then pass the text file to diskpart:

```
diskpart.exe /s C:\mycommands.txt
```